# Why am I only getting one row from this Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I'm querying my database and expecting to get three rows back, but am only getting one.

Here is my table structure:

[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT M.MovieTitle, D.Director
FROM dbo.MOVIES_MAIN M, dbo.DIRECTORS D, dbo.DIRECTORS_MOVIES_M2M M2M
WHERE M.MovieId = 'tt0010721'
AND M.MovieId = M2M.MovieId
AND D.DirectorId = M2M.DirectorId
```

This is what's in the Many-to-Many table for the movieId (rectangled):

[image]

...and here is the result, a single row:

[image]

I expect/want to get all three Directors seen in the Many-to-Many table (nm0085133, nm0349785, and nm0674600) but only get the one. Why? Apparently my SQL is wrong, but I don't know just where it is wrong.

Note, from google:

*Tarnished Reputations is a 1920 American silent adventure drama film directed by Herbert Blache, Alice Guy-Blaché, and Léonce Perret*

Comment: Check if all 3 values of directorId from M2M, exist in the DIRECTORS table.

Comment: (Row level) Permissions? Wrong database connection? Either way, it's long past time you stopped using that 31 year old `JOIN` syntax. Maybe "updating" the more *recent* ANSI-92 Syntax might answer the question: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @lptr: Yes, that's the problem. I'll have to go back and see why they didn't get populated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Alice&Perret already exist with different ids (just update the m2m table with the correct ids, if they do exist in DIRECTORS)

Comment: You should not use the old obsolete join syntax. https://dzone.com/articles/finding-code-smells-using-sql-prompt-old-style-joi

Comment: @SteveFord: Why should I not use it if it works? Why is the new way (whatever that is) better?

Comment: If you are going to bounty this, at least take the time to make it consumable... Someone with almost 20K reputation should know how useless images of code is; don't expect us to transcribe something you can trivially copy and paste from your IDE to your web browser. Data, as well, should not be images; take the time to put it into DDL and DML statements, or at least (well formatted) tabular formatted `text`.  Provide us with an [mre] so we don't have to second guess the problem(s) and waste our time transcribing code that we should be able to just highlight and copy.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Old style syntax is more difficult to read and is prone to errors (forgetting a join clause in the where clause leads to a CROSS JOIN rather than an Error). The old style outer joins have been deprecated since 2008 and discontinued since 2012. So if you need an outer join you could end up mixing 2 different styles.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing query and the screen copy from the bridge table really make it look like only one out of the three directors exists in the `directors` table - so the `inner join` filters out the two others.

You could run the query as a `left join` (which is easy of we use *standard* join syntax):

```
select m.movietitle, dm.movieid, d.director
from directors_movies_m2m dm
inner join movies_main m on dm.movieid = m.movieid
left join directors d on d.directorid = dm.directorid
where dm.movieid = 'tt0010721'
```

"Missing" directors will show up as `null` in the resultset - you can then decided what to do next (maybe fix your data).

*Assuming* that this solves the problem: consider setting up foreign key constraint in the bridge table to prevent "orphan" rows. The DDL of the table could look like:

```
create table directors_movies_m2m (
    id         int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    movieid    int references movies_main(movieid),
    directorid int references directors(directorid)
);
```